# How does my iPhone know if the charger is non-genuine?

Tags: iphone

Surely USB is just wires, how does it know whether or not the cable that is connected is a genuine apple one?

Comment: There is a chip in the cable.  This fact is well documented.

Comment: I did look, but couldn't find much info on it.

Comment: Its even documented on the Apple website.  Here is a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=non-genuine+apple.com&gbv=2&oq=non-genuine+apple.com&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0i22i30l2.430.2210.0.2440.12.9.0.0.0.0.350.840.2-2j1.3.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..9.3.840.AberM6tIjvA) with tons of results

Comment: USB is just wires, but the other end of the wires can easily be connected to something.

Comment: Apple doesn't use a "USB" cable it uses a `lighting` cable for all(or at least 99%) of its current generation of mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chip in the charger which the iPhone knows to look for.

http://gizmodo.com/5945889/some-third-party-adapters-might-not-work-with-your-new-iphone/all